# Rotate two tables including caption on the same page

Tags: tables, floats, rotating, adjustbox, sidewaystable

I want to rotate two tables including their captions and display them on the same page.
I tried using sideways tables but there each table is forced on a new page.
I currently use adjustbox with {angle=90}
I want the tables to be placed as follows but I want the captions to rotate too.
Thanks!

[image: adjustedbox captions]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
a   & b   & c   & d    \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ... 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table1}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
a   & b   & c   & d    \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ... 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will you have other, non-rotated text on the page?

Comment: No, the two tables will fill out the whole page

Comment: In this case, use the `landscape` environment (package `lscape`).

Comment: could you provide code? I tried landscape and either the tables were forced on two pages or they were positioned next to each other, not on top of each other like in the screenshot above

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can place 2 `minipage` environments, each with a `tabular` environment and `\caption` and `\label` directives, side by side inside a `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
a   & b   & c   & d    \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
a   & b   & c   & d    \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...  \\
... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{minipage}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code with the `landscape` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{l}}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
a & b & c & d & e \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: A variant code, using the `floatrow` package, for tables above each other, w.r.t. the normal page orientation:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{floatrow}{2}
\ttabbox{\caption{Caption}\label{tab:table1}}{\begin{tabular}{*{8}{l}}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}}
\ttabbox{\caption{Caption}\label{tab:table2}}{\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
a & b & c & d & e \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I want the tables to be on top of each other like in the screenshot, not next to each other because the real tables do not fit next to each other

Comment: Oh! You mean the vertical spacing? I added it  because I found it looked not so nice without it. Just remove `\vskip 1cm`.

Comment: I am really thankful for you taking the time! But this is not exactly what I mean, I need the tables to be on TOP of each other, like in the screenshot, in the solution you provided they are NEXT to each other. I am really stuck on this, so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: They're on top of each other when you turn the page  to read them.  You want them  to be next to each other when you read them?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry for the imprecise description. Mico provided such an answer

Comment: I've added a variant with `floatrow`.