# adjustbox has a wrong reference at \ref

Tags: tables, adjustbox

To rotate a table, I used `\begin{adjustbox}`. But \ref{} shows a wrong ID when I refer to it, and \centering doesn't work. How to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

Here are the environment used in the tex file:

```
\documentclass{sokendai_thesis} % https://github.com/koikezlemma/phd_thesis_template/blob/master/sokendai_thesis.cls

\usepackage{adjustbox, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{AA }


Table \ref{tab:testtable}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566793/rotate-two-tables-including-caption-on-the-same-page
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90, caption={Summary of XXX.}, float=table}\label{tab:testtable}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
& A       &  B    & C \\
\midrule
& 1       &  2   & 3 \\
& 1       &  2    &3  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the `\label` as part of the `caption` key-value option:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{..., caption={Summary of XXX.\label{tab:testtable}}, ...}
  %...
\end{adjustbox}
```